# How do I patch, compile & upgrade Thunar with a recently released patch... the Arch way?

Tags: manjaro, patch

There's been a [patch](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13481) recently that fixes a very annoying bug in Thunar, which has the latter lock up when files change in the currently open directory. I don't want to wait and would like to download the source, patch, compile and upgrade Thunar **1.6.11** on my **Manjaro 17.0.1** system. Is there a guide how to do it the right... I mean the Arch way? (pun intended.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a `PKGBUILD`, use `makepkg` to build the package and use `pacman` to install it.

You can start with [thunar-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/thunar-git/), get it with the [Download snapshot](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/thunar-git.tar.gz) link. Download the patch, put it in the same directory and add the patch command just before the call to `autogen.sh` in the build function of the `PKGBUILD`.

Maybe you want to start with the default PKGBUILD of manjaro if thunar-git doesn't work with your version of xfce.

**Update**: The [patch](https://git.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/commit/?id=4dd549db77838c9345f10a72f10e705f8ae327d4) is already pushed to git, so thunar-git from aur might work for you without modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. From what you wrote, turns out I just had to run `yaourt -S thunar-git`. I'll report if the bug is fixed or not.

Comment: That would be the 'proscribed arch way' ;)

Comment: Ah... oops... About Manjaro? ;-)

Comment: I' don't know about Manjaro, but have a look on this page: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers#Comparison_table You might find a better one.

Comment: I see... All but `yaourt` in fact, that is :-D

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of the question, to patch, compile and upgrade the Arch way, I think you should download from the AUR the corresponding package (I mean, the git version if possible, since that's what developer patches usually apply to), then have something [like](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Patching_packages#Applying_patches) this in its PKGBUILD:

```
prepare() {
wget -O "${startdir}"/patch.diff https://bugzilla.xfce.org/attachment.cgi?id=7074
patch -p1 -i "${startdir}"/patch.diff -d "${srcdir}/${pkgname}"
}
```

Replace the last arguments of either command with whatever the patch URL and actual-root-folder-the-patch-file-expects are.